# List where Clause with Remove

Tags: c#, linq, list

The code below works successfully to remove if a value exists in a list. How do I add a where clause such that only for list items where sType = "File"

```
MyGlobals.lstNewItems.RemoveAll(item => item.sItemName == rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString());
```

**Pseudo Code for what i want**

```
MyGlobals.lstNewItems.Where(y => y.sType == "File").RemoveAll(item => item.sItemName == rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString());
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to remove all of the items where *both* conditions are true, then simply AND them together:

```
MyGlobals.lstNewItems.RemoveAll(item => 
    item.sItemName == rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString()
    && item.sType == "File");
```